# Vuex axios issue array updates

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

I'm currently having an issue with VueJS vuex and Axios :

I'm getting an array with axios -> looping on that array to populate its childs this way :
"Rubriques" has a lot of self relations so one rubrique can have a multiple child rubrique

> ACTIONS :

```
  actions: {
    get_main_rubriques: ({ commit }) => {
      axios.get('http://localhost:8180/unv-api/rubrique/search/rsql?query=niveau==1')
        .then(resp => {
          let results = resp.data._embedded.rubriques
          results.forEach(element => {
            axios.get('http://localhost:8180/unv-api/rubrique/search/rsql?query=idpere==' + element.id)
              .then((result) => {
                element.childs = result.data._embedded.rubriques
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
              })
          })
          console.log(results)
          commit('MUTE_MAIN_RUBRIQUES', results)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    }
  }
```

> Mutations :

```
MUTE_MAIN_RUBRIQUES: (state, rubrique) => {
      state.rubriques = rubrique
    }
```

> APP.VUE

```
computed: {
    ...mapState([
      'rubriques'
    ])
  },
  created: function () {
    this.$store.dispatch('get_main_rubriques')
  }

<b-dropdown  v-for="item in rubriques" :key="item.id"  v-bind:text="item.libelle" id="ddown1" class="m-md-1">
       <b-dropdown-item-button v-for="child in item.childs" :key="child.id"  v-bind:text="child.libelle">
         {{ child.id }} - {{ child.libelle }}
       </b-dropdown-item-button>
</b-dropdown>
```

Issue is : the parent dropdown are displaying without any problem but childs are not, they are not present in the state either BUT they are present in the `console.log(results)` before the `commit` in my action.

Am I doing something wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried Vue.set(state, 'rubriques', rubrique) ?

Comment: @Darem I did yes, doesn't work either, the State 'rubriques' still don't have childs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move `commit('MUTE_MAIN_RUBRIQUES', results)` to sit inside the inner `then` block, to make sure it will get executed after you get back the response:

```
  actions: {
    get_main_rubriques: ({ commit }) => {
      axios.get('http://localhost:8180/unv-api/rubrique/search/rsql?query=niveau==1')
        .then(resp => {
          let results = resp.data._embedded.rubriques
          results.forEach(element => {
            axios.get('http://localhost:8180/unv-api/rubrique/search/rsql?query=idpere==' + element.id)
              .then((result) => {
                element.childs = result.data._embedded.rubriques;
                console.log(results);
                commit('MUTE_MAIN_RUBRIQUES', results);
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
              })
          })
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    }
  }
```

to understand why its not working on your way, read more about [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and asynchronous operation.

Comment: Alright thanks it's working great, I created an async function instead and it worked too but I didn't know that axios was already waiting for the response before entering in the .then.

I've learned something today. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that computed properties do not do deep watching, see [computed property of array is difficult to trigger](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7093#issuecomment-346044953)

This code

```js
computed: {
  ...mapState([
    'rubriques'
  ])
}
```

references the parent `rubriques` array and watches that, but not the child properties `childs`.

When you look at the console, you might see a small 'i' for info that says the value is updated 'just now'. This means by the time you look at it, it already has the child values - but that is probably not the case when the `commit()` runs.

So, the parents get added and your child fetches keep running but have a reference to their parents, so eventually the children get added correctly to the store.

One way to handle it is to add a deep watcher which uses `$forceUpdate()` to re-render the DOM

```js
watch: {
  rubriques: {
    handler: function (after, before) {
      this.$forceUpdate()
    },
    deep: true,
  }
}
```

@Efrat's answer is probably better - you would effectively wait for all child data before posting parents to the store. That way you have just one DOM refresh (and less code).